# how to remove a image on same page using java script?

Tags: javascript, jsp

i tried some code..

```
function loadImages() {

     var img = document.createElement("img");
        img.src = "/images/answers/${record1.answer_id}.png";
        img.id = "answer_id";
}
function removeFile(){
     var elements = document.getElementsById('/images/answers/${record1.answer_id}.png').document.getElementsByTagName('img');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
var elements = document.getElementById("answer_id");
elements.parentNode.removeChild(elements);
```

in `document.getElementsById('/images/answers/${record1.answer_id}.png')` you are trying to get the element using its 'src' and `getElementsById` must be `getElementById`

Comment: can you post some of your codes..or check your getElementById...you have an extra 's'.

Comment: ya i removed 's' from there

Comment: <tr>
         <td class="data">
          D. <form:input path="answer[3]" maxlength="250" size="50" id="answer_id"/><br>&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;<strong><fmt:message key="label.or"/></strong><br>
          <input type="file" name="answerImage[3]"/>
          <c:out value="${editInsOrgQuestionBankReferenceForm.answerImage[3]}"/>&nbsp;[<a href="javascript:removeFile();"><fmt:message key="link.removeFile"/></a>]
          <td class="data"><form:checkbox path="flag[3]" value="true"/>
         </td>
          </tr>

Comment: <script type="text/javascript">
function init()
 {
  var maxLenArray = new Array('questionId||500');
   
  initMaxLengthAttributes(maxLenArray);
 }
  YAHOO.util.Event.onDOMReady(init);

</script>

<script type="text/javascript">

function loadImages() {
var elements = document.getElementById("answer_id");
document.getElementById('answer_id').remove();
}
</script>

Comment: wait.your code for loadImages isnt right... @SomeKittens code belongs to removeFile()

Comment: thanks for your nice solution but remove should not be a button it should be a link.. when u add it should not come while you are editing this should come..

Comment: i tried lot of modifications but i m not getting proper logic for that concept

Answer (score 0):

To hide the element:

```
document.getElementById('answer_id').style.display = 'none';
```

To remove it completely

```
document.getElementById('answer_id').remove();
```